# Bluetooth headphones have terrible sound quality when using any microphone

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11, bluetooth, microphone

I have a pair of SHURE Aonic 40 headphones which are connected via bluetooth to my laptop running Windows 11.

The sound is fine when using it to watch videos and gaming, but when using discord or any other kind of call app that could be using the built-in microphone of the headphones the sound quality drops. Note that i am NOT using the microphone of the headphones but the built-in one of my laptop.

I have even disabled the headphones microphone using windows sound settings.

I also don't have two different audio-output options when chosing the headphones. There is only one called "Shure Aonic 40".

I've scrolled through so many questions and search results but haven't found anything to solve my specific problem. Any thoughts or ideas are welcome at this point.

Thanks

Comment: This is absolutely a feature of Bluetooth and has been the case for the last 20 years. Bluetooth audio just sucks when you use the microphone and until we completely redesign it or completely ditch it in favour of something that doesn't suck then we are stuck with this awful behaviour.

Comment: In all honesty if you want wireless audio then you would be better off getting any of the large number of dedicated wireless gaming headsets, though they will all come with their own USB dongle. If they mention Bluetooth then you will be stuck with this same behaviour you are seeing.